# Screen freezes Meteor.js

Tags: javascript, meteor

I have a meteor app and there are some actions I take that freeze the screen (both Chrome and Safari). I can't scroll down the screen till I click the refresh button.
When a player joins a league in my app this happens, for example.

I'm using iron-router and Bootstrap 3.0.3. I use modals in Bootstrap as well, but I'm not sure they have anything to do with the screen freezing.

Any advice on how I can go about solving this problem? I don't think the screen ever unfreezes till I click refresh.
Is there a way for me to simulate clicking the refresh button? (i.e. clearing all session settings and reloading the page).

I just don't know where to start debugging and this problem has been bugging me for a while.

Comment: It looks like you might have a Deps error. When it freezes have a look at your javascript console and paste the contents here

Comment: There are no errors in the JS console.

Comment: Do any of the actions occur when subscriptions change? This used to happen on one of my apps when a substantial (hundreds) of subscription documents were loaded at a time.

Comment: Yes. I think so. But the collections that change aren't massive. I can subscribe to every collection I have and it only takes about 10 seconds to load a page. I think I've solved the problem though. I just do window.href.location = "some_link" and that reloads the page fine. the problem may have been that i was trying to make big changes to the DOM that caused the freeze. not sure